# Remove links with hash symbol from string

Tags: php, regex, url

I have a database with HTML content and it has some text with links. Some texts have hash symbol in their URLs, some others no.

I need to delete the links with hash symbol, keeping those with **no** hash symbol on it.

**Example:**

Input:

```
<a href="http://example.com/books/1">The Lord of the Rings</a>
<ul>
    <li><a   href="http://example.com/books/1#c1" >Chapter 1</a></li>
    <li><a name="name before href" href="http://example.com/books/1#c2">Chapter 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/1#c3" name="name after href">Chapter 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/1#cN" target="_blank">Chapter N</a></li>
</ul>
<br><br>
<a href="http://example.com/books/1">Harry Potter</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/2#c1" target="_self">Chapter 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/2#c2" name="some have name" title="some others have title" >Chapter 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/2#c3">Chapter 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/2#cN"  >Chapter N</a></li>
</ul>
```

Desired Output:

```
<a href="http://example.com/books/1">The Lord of the Rings</a>
<ul>
    <li>Chapter 1</li>
    <li>Chapter 2</li>
    <li>Chapter 3</li>
    <li>Chapter N</li>
</ul>
<br><br>
<a href="http://example.com/books/2">Harry Potter</a>
<ul>
    <li>Chapter 1</li>
    <li>Chapter 2</li>
    <li>Chapter 3</li>
    <li>Chapter N</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying with this code, but it delete all the links and I want to keep those with no hash symbol.

```
$content = preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $content);
```

So, currently I am getting this:

```
The Lord of the Rings
<ul>
    <li>Chapter 1</li>
    <li>Chapter 2</li>
    <li>Chapter 3</li>
    <li>Chapter N</li>
</ul>
<br><br>
Harry Potter
<ul>
    <li>Chapter 1</li>
    <li>Chapter 2</li>
    <li>Chapter 3</li>
    <li>Chapter N</li>
</ul>
```

More details:

- I am using PHP.
- The only reference I have to know what links to delete is de # symbol.
- Some links have new line.

Example:

```
<a href="http://example.com">
    new line</a>
or
<a href="http://example.com">new
    line</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Post your code thus far.

Comment: @fubar Done. Thanks.

Comment: Parsing inconsitent HTML with regular expressions is very unreliable. Is this HTML that you've written, and can standardise, or are you crawling another site for it? You'd probably be better served using something like `DOMDocument`, if the HTML is even valid.

Comment: @fubar is spot on with the `DOMDocument` and if you use that in conjunction with my answer, you can parse through the HTML and delete the lines with a `#`. Regex is good for a single line, but regex by itself can't parse the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex statement matches the examples you've given. It detects those URL's with a # somewhere in the url. You can then write a replace statement and swap them all the text from capture group \1

```
<a(?:\s+name=".*?")?\s+href=.*?#.*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

[Regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/c2Z4RC/1)

Comment: This almost works. Some links have a new lines and does not work o those. I am going to add and example at the bottom, for you to understand.

Comment: Added the example of links with new lines. Your regex works well except for this kind of links.

Comment: Adapted Regex Statement; <a(?:\s+name=".*?")?\s+href=.*?#.*?>([\s\S]+?)<\/a>

Comment: Just, Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid using regex, instead you should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHtml('
<a href="http://example.com/books/1">The Lord of the Rings</a>
<ul>
    <li><a   href="http://example.com/books/1#c1" >Chapter 1</a></li>
    <li><a name="name before href" href="http://example.com/books/1#c2">Chapter 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/1#c3" name="name after href">Chapter 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/1#cN" target="_blank">Chapter N</a></li>
</ul>
<br><br>
<a href="http://example.com/books/1">Harry Potter</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/2#c1" target="_self">Chapter 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/2#c2" name="some have name" title="some others have title" >Chapter 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/2#c3">Chapter 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books/2#cN"  >Chapter N</a></li>
</ul>
', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("//a") as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');

    // link has a # in it, so replace with the links title
    if (strpos($href, '#') !== false) {
        $link->parentNode->nodeValue = $link->nodeValue;
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

https://3v4l.org/8FQYb

**Result:**

```
<a href="http://example.com/books/1">The Lord of the Rings<ul>
    <li>Chapter 1</li>
    <li>Chapter 2</li>
    <li>Chapter 3</li>
    <li>Chapter N</li>
</ul><br><br><a href="http://example.com/books/1">Harry Potter</a><ul>
    <li>Chapter 1</li>
    <li>Chapter 2</li>
    <li>Chapter 3</li>
    <li>Chapter N</li>
</ul></a>
```

Comment: Im my code, it does not solved all the links. but all those not solved by Chromane original answer. Really Appreciate it.

Comment: Whats it not solving? (update your question with complete HTML example) Im happy to update.

Comment: Chromane's update solved it. Thanks anyway, I appreciate your help and up voted it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

After parsing through the HTML and selecting all the HTML links, you could use a `foreach` loop and `str_replace` on the condition that the string contains a pound/hash symbol.

```
<?php
//Save HTML code as an object using DOMDocument ($links) for parsing
foreach($links as $line) {
    if (str_pos($line, '#')) {
        str_replace($line, '', $links);
    }
}
?>
```

This would replace each line with a pound/hash symbol with a blank line and would be treated as such by the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use following pattern to match `<a href=...>` and `</a>` in the text, and replace the matched text with empty string.

```
(?<=<li>)<a.+?>|</a>(?=</li>)
```

This is to remove strings unwanted, instead of replacing whole text with wanted.

Comment: This is a good idea, but not all the unwanted links are inside of `<li>` tags. But I know the part I used in the example does... thanks anyway.